# Why does JSON parsing with jsonpath-plus throw a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

When my code calls [jsonpath-plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath), it's getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` (where `value` is the name of a child that I want to check). This occurs whenever the object provided in the `json' parameter has a null property. My path includes a conditional selector:

```js
JSONPath({json: {content: null}, path: "$..[?(@.value)]"}
```

This is a simple case that always causes `TypeError` to be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a changed behavior introduced in jsonpath-plus version 5.0.4 around April 1, 2021. In verions 5.0.2 & 5.0.3, the conditional selector simply does not match the object. This appears to be a breaking change, so one would hope it will be reverted back in the next patch release. In the mean time, I'm using 5.0.3.

The maintainer has [indicated that the breaking change is a bug-fix](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath/issues/149), so it's unlikely that the change will be reverted.